# History of Creation Ex Nihilo

Tags: history, creation

Is it known whether creation from nothing has always been the mainstream jewish belief (as far back as is possible to tell)? Were there notable groups within Judaism that, instead of going with the ex nihilo theory, would view creation from the [tohu va'vohu view (chaos)](https://www.thetorah.com/article/creating-order-from-tohu-and-bohu)?

Has there been a evolution of opinion within Rabbinic Judaism on Creation Ex Nihilo and how to view creation ex nihilo in connection to creation from chaos, e.g. tohu v'bohu?

For [context](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94634/history-of-creatio-ex-nihilo):
I am trying to narrow down when and how creatino ex nihilo was introduced as a concept within Judaism. It's of course possible that this has always been the case, or that we can't tell, but I doubt it.

Comment: Judaism believes there was a stage of chaos: והארץ היתה תהו ובהו

Comment: @shmosel Ok, by creation from chaos I mean: creation from primordial, uncreated, chaos. Is that the case with this stage of chaos?

Comment: @kutschkem I think in this case the MY guideline of "explain where your question is coming from" is particularly useful here. If we knew why you are asking, what prompted the question, what you are getting at, we can answer it better. Of course, originally, there was nothing but God. There was also a stage of "tohu" as shmosel has stated. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Better?

Comment: @kutschkem much better, thanks. I think this question is likely off topic for this site, Mi Yodeya is very specifically about Judaism, and this dips into comparative religion, and it's main thrust is one of general history.

Comment: As Rabbi Kaii said, in order to make sure your question isn't labeled "off topic" and "comparative" you can ask specifically about what the Jewish perspective is on the Ex Nihilo topic. What did the Sages write etc...

Comment: @Shmuel I am not familiar with the Sages, if I reformulate to ask along the lines of who was the first Sage to talk about / introduce creatio ex nihilo, is that still a sensible question? Will this invalidate your answer for example? How can I properly reformulate without making your answer obsolete? Basically I am interested in whether or not one can see a sort of evolution of opinion/belief over time regarding what the creation is.

Comment: I would ask this: Has there been a evolution of opinion within Rabbinic Judaism on Creation Ex Nihilo and how to view creation ex nihilo in connection to creation from chaos, e.g. tohu v'bohu?  -

Comment: @kutschkem it might be very hard to give you a clear answer that you can accept, from where you are coming from. Firstly, the idea of "from nothing" and "from chaos" is very esoteric, so we'd have to clarify that, if even possible. Secondly, finding our "earliest source" isn't a normal practice for a question about "evolution of the idea" because we take for granted that our commentators teach from a tradition that goes all the way back to Sinai. So even if the earliest we have is the Rambam or Ramban discussing "bara" and "yesh meyin" as "from nothing", that's very unlikely their novelty

Comment: @kutschkem I've edited your question. Please feel free to revert it back if this does not cover what you were asking for in the first place, but I think it does.

Comment: @Shmuel Thanks, I think it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it mainstream? Well, the Rambam discussed it many times, including multiple times in his work The Guide for the Perplexed. Besides that, many meforshim (commentator) also discuss this topic in their commentaries on the Torah. I do not know if this qualifies it as "mainstream".

The Rambam (Maimonides) in his Guide for the Perplexed [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.50.3?ven=Guide_for_the_Perplexed,_English_Translation,_Friedlander_(1903)&lang=bi) clearly that:

> It is one of the fundamental principles of the Law that the Universe has been created ex nihilo, and that of the human race, one individual being, Adam, was created.

Another commentator, the Kli Yakar, [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Genesis.1.1.8?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi) that it is the foundation of the entire Torah.

Rabbi Yosef Albo, however, author of the famous work Sefer HaIkkarim writes in [Maamar 1:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_1.12.1?lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en):

> Creation ex nihilo is a dogma which every one who professes a divine law is obliged to believe, in the same way as he who professes the Law of Moses is obliged to believe that the earth opened her mouth and swallowed up Korah and his congregation, because they rebelled against Moses. But it is not one of the fundamental principles of divine law, whose existence can not be conceived without it. The story of creation at the beginning of the Torah is not intended to teach that creation ex nihilo is a fundamental principle of the Torah, as many authorities have thought.

However, see [this article](https://www.thetorah.com/article/creating-order-from-tohu-and-bohu) where it says that it was not an universal accepted idea amongst our sages.

Comment: To be fair, I have no idea what "mainstream" in Judaism is, that's just what the people in Christianity.SE seem to think.

Comment: Did you check out the article linked above? It goes through several views on this subject.

Comment: Yes, I did, it was pretty good.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the check-mark and I hope things are more clear now. Please let me know if something could be added to the answer.